# If $f'(x_0) \neq 0$, then $f$ is injective on some neighborhood of $x_0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I suspect that if $f$ is differentable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0)$ is not zero, then $f$ is injective on some open set around $x_0$.

How would one prove it? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Hint: if $f$ is differentable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0) \ne 0$, then $f$ is *strictly monotonic* in an open set around $x_0$.

Comment: If you assume the derivative to be continuous, this is a well-known theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem .

Comment: This is probably one of my favourite counterexamples in calculus. It just shows how non-intuitive mathematics can be.

Comment: @mic: your claim is wrong. it only means that $f$ is strictly monotone at $x_{0}$ and not in an open set containing $x_{0}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim is (or *should be*, apparently) famously **false**. Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0&\text{if }x=0\\ x+x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$$

Its derivative is $$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if }x=0\\ 1+2x\sin\frac1{x^2}-\frac{2}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$$

You can see (using Darboux theorem) that $f'$ sends surjectively any $[0,\varepsilon)$ onto the whole $\Bbb R$, hence $f$ is not monotone in any neighbourhood of $0$. Since a continuous function is injective in an interval if and only if it is strictly monotone, $f|_{(-\varepsilon,\,\varepsilon)}$ is not injective.

Of course, $f'$ is **not continuous** in this (though it exists on the whole $\Bbb R$, which is even stronger than your request).

**Added:** On second thought, it is perhaps best to highlight more precisely the details of the reason why this is a counterexample.

1. For an (open) interval $I$, a continuous function $f:I\to \Bbb R$ is injective if and only if it is strictly monotone.
2. Thus, a differentiable function $f:I\to \Bbb R$ is injective only if either $\forall x\in I,\ f'(x)\ge 0$ or $\forall x\in I,\ f'(x)\le 0$
3. The one I've mentioned is a function $f$ such that $\liminf_{x\to0^+} f'(x)<0<\limsup_{x\to0^+} f'(x)$. By (1) and (2), it cannot be monotone in any interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, despite satisfying $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: This example is better than the one which involves $x^{2}\sin(1/x)$ as it is easy to see here that $f'$ maps $[0, \epsilon)$ to whole of $\mathbb{R}$ and thus takes both positive and negative values. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. However, as it had been pointed out elsewhere, $x+\alpha x^2\sin\frac1x$ for sufficiently large $\alpha$ provides a counterexample with $f'$ Riemann-integrable for basically the same effort in proving non-monotonicity.

Comment: Not sure why you are invoking Darboux.

Comment: @zhw In my mind, I was thinking about proving that $f'([0,\varepsilon))=\Bbb R$ by showing that $\liminf_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)=-\infty$ and $\limsup_{x\to0^+} f'(x)=+\infty$. This implies surjectivity because derivatives have the intermediate value property. However, now that you mention it, I see that it is largely unnecessary!